# Почему при итерации объекта последний ключ выводится первым?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, почему цикл выводит последний элемент первым?

```js
let map = new Map([
  ['name', 'Sergey'],
  ['age', 20],
  [123, 'число']
]);
for (let key in Object.fromEntries(map)) {
  console.log(key);
} // 123, name, age
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pg5p.jpg

Comment: Мне кажется, что числа в качестве ключа воспринимаются как индекс итерируемого объекта и обрабатываются первыми. В пользу этого говорит еще и то, что отрицательные числа не учитываются и будут выдаваться в указанной вами последовательности

Comment: @Igor неправда. Как раз Map хранит в порядке добавления. Но автор из Map сделал объект, а потом взял из него ключи.